# CanvasJS Label Issue on Bar Chart

Tags: php, canvasjs

I have a vote counting system in place using CanvasJS to create the graphs. I use Pie and Bar chart graphs.

In my Bar Chart [image: view here please] there seems to be an issue where all the labels for each column did show.. and when the count got above around 1000, they stopped showing every other label. I am not sure if this is a bug or something I can fix now, but I couldn't see anything online?

Answer (score 1):

Set [interval](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/interval/) to 1 in x-axis, which force to show all labels. Labels are skipped automatically to avoid overlapping.